# Custom exception works with python 2.76 but not 2.4

Tags: python, exception, python-2.4

I need some help. Originally this was part of some code that was running under python 2.76. This now needs to run under a vanilla python 2.4 install. I learned under 2.76 and am having trouble figuring out how to tweak this to work with 2.4.

This is a custom exception that in other places sometimes I'll pass stdout/stderr or other information to the exception object to be used elsewhere.

Here is the exception:

```
class OpenSSLWalletError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, command=None, stdout=None, stderr=None):
        super(OpenSSLWalletError, self).__init__(message)
        self._message   = message
        self._command   = command
        self._stdout    = stdout
        self._stderr    = stderr
```

Under 2.4 it complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testpywallet.py", line 20, in ?
    user = w.get("rest_ro.userX")
  File "./openssl.py", line 167, in get
    raise OpenSSLWalletError("Error: key '%s' not found in wallet '%s'" % (key_name, self.wallet), None, None, None)
  File "./openssl.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(OpenSSLWalletError, self).__init__(message)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score 1):

`super()` only works with new-style classes. In Python 2.4, exceptions do not inherit from `object`, they are still old-style classes.

Call the parent constructor directly:

```
class OpenSSLWalletError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, command=None, stdout=None, stderr=None):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        self._message   = message
        self._command   = command
        self._stdout    = stdout
        self._stderr    = stderr
```

The 2.4 exception machinery cannot handle new-style classes, so mixing in `object` won't work.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed... I couldn't find any 2.4 documentation that covered a custom exception where you're adding extra data fields like I'm doing.